# How to further automate Teamcity

Tags: deployment, automation, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have successfully configured my project for build in TeamCity. Going a step more, I want to run a deployment script once a build completes successfully. The deployment script is a simple bash command. To make the question more simpler, how would I invoke a shell command once a build successfully completes in Teamcity.

Please help

Comment: What does this have to do with Ruby on Rails?

Comment: @edgerunner: I am trying to invoke a rails build here. Thought tagging this would be helpful in me getting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeamCity 6.0 has a new feature called [Multiple Build Steps](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/What%27s+New+in+TeamCity+6.0#What%27sNewinTeamCity6.0-Multiplebuildsteps):

> Multiple Build Steps: Now any build configuration can be comprised of unlimited number of build steps, where each step is represented by a build runner. Don’t limit yourself, and combine as many build runners into one configuration as you need. Feel free to call a NAnt script before compiling VS solutions, run inspections and duplicates finder after your ANT build, add NUnit tests after your Rake build, and so on.

So you can [add a new build step](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Configuring+Build+Steps) with the [command line runner](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Command+Line) which will execute your shell script.